# what is the proper way to customize bootstrap for RTL languages?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left

I am building a template for the Arabic language based on bootstrap, I use **sass** with **gulp** to make customization to **bootstrap 3**. does bootstrap behave well if i just set the **rtl** direction on the html tag, or is there another version of bootstrap for **rtl** **languages** or should i do something else above that?. i am really confused and waste a lot of time customizing bootstrap.

PS: *sorry if this question does not come along with the rules of this site, and if that so, just give me pointers on where to ask this question instead of down voting.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library:

which, as far as I know, is the best to convert to RTL CSS

https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss